# Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16 при попытке обновить базу данных

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, ssms

Всем привет. При попытке обновить базу данных вылезает эта ошибка:

> > Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16
> > The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Product_ApplicationType_ApplicationId". The conflict occurred in database "Rocky", table "dbo.ApplicationType", column 'Id'.
> > PM>

Что делать?

20220828104535_AddApplicationTypeToProduct.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace Rocky.Migrations
{
    public partial class AddApplicationTypeToProduct : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "ApplicationId",
                table: "Product",
                type: "int",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: 0);

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Product_ApplicationId",
                table: "Product",
                column: "ApplicationId");

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Product_ApplicationType_ApplicationId",
                table: "Product",
                column: "ApplicationId",
                principalTable: "ApplicationType",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Product_ApplicationType_ApplicationId",
                table: "Product");

            migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
                name: "IX_Product_ApplicationId",
                table: "Product");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "ApplicationId",
                table: "Product");
        }
    }
}
```

Модель applicationtype.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rocky.Models
{
    public class ApplicationType
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Укажите точную версию EF. Уберите нерелевантные метки.

Comment: Необходимо знать, что было **до** этой миграции. Таблица для типа `ApplicationType` уже была в БД? Или создаётся тоже в этой миграции?

Comment: В таблицу `Product` добавляется колонка с дефолтным значением `0`. Если такого значения нет в таблице `ApplicationType`, то будет ошибка. Никому неведомо, какие у вас требования к данным. Вероятно, нужно в миграцию добавить sql-запрос `update`, наподобие https://stackoverflow.com/a/43739826/5045688

Answer (score 0):

> " [Display(Name="Application Type")] public int ApplicationTypeId {
> get; set; } [ForeignKey("ApplicationTypeId")] public virtual
> ApplicationType ApplicationType { get; set; } " use ApplicationTypeId
> instead of ApplicationId

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

удали все данные из таблицы (если это учебный проект то это не критично) и выполни update-database.  У меня все сработало[image: введите сюда описание изображения]